# How to control width of ngbSlide in NgbCarousel of ngbootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

[image]How to control width of ngbSlide  in NgbCarousel of ngbootstrap

I am not able to change the width of  carousel-item div present in NgbCarousel.
below is the caurosal item sample

```
<ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

its width is 100% how can i reduce it to 25%. ng-template will render into carusal item where its width is coming 100%. I have tried to put a ngclass attribute over ng-template tag but its throwing runtime error as below :

```
    <ng-template ngbSlide [ngClass]="'ddd'">

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.DefaultDomRenderer2.addClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem there (and cause of the error) is that `<ng-template>` are not rendered, they are placeholders, so there is no sense in adding a class to something that is not rendered right?

You might as well replace it with a `<div>` wrapper:

```
<div ngbSlide [ngClass]="'ddd'">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```